# Modulus operation on other side of equation?

Tags: math, modulus

If

```
I = (V+13) % 26
```

Then what is V in terms of 'I'. Basically how can you take the Mod operator on the other side of equation ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about solving a mathematical equation.

Comment: doesnt look like you really tried.  Have you tried to solve for V at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I = (V+13) %26
```

This means `V+13 = k*26 + I, and k=Z, I=[0,1,...,26-1]`.   **(1)**

so

**V = k*26 + I -13**

now, because `I` is remainder from division by `26, I=[0,1,...,26-1]`.
This means:

`I%26=I`, `I` divided by `26` is just `I`.

so:

```
I = (V+13) %26

I%26 = (V+13) %26
```

this is not the same as `I%26 = (V+13)` 
because `I%26 = (V+13)` implies  `V+13 = [0,1,...,26-1]` what contradicts **(1)**, (`V+13` **might be greater** than `26-1`).

---

Corollary:

V = (I%26) - 13  is not correct

V = (I%26) - 13 + k*26, k=Z is correct

Comment: Well, **K** is an unknown quantity depends upon **Z**... which i think is really very important ... what is Z over here?? theoretically your solution seems correct but practically involves 2 unknown quantities....